# I need help improving my normal map baking for game assets

Tags: normals, baking

I started with Blender about 2 months ago. I use that and 3dcoat to make models. I've made a lot of models i'm really happy with, but when it comes to the normal map baking process it's pretty much been a "fake it til I make it" approach. So far I've only modeled weaponry. I honestly don't understand baking still despite modeling nearly 20 different weapons so far. Here's my work flow

1. Make low res model
2. Make hi res model
3. UV Unwrap low res model
4. Use Blender to bake Normals
5. Import everything into 3dcoat and texture it

This time I made a spiked mace/hammer. Pretty much I get weird stretching, shading and just plain weird jagged lines when I bake. I hate using xNormal so I bake within Blender. I followed BlenderGuru's normal baking process and maybe I am forgetting something crucial. I've just gotten to a point where I try to hide the imperfections as best as I can in the texturing process.

I've found that when I have really bright colors on the normal map, adding more edge loops to the low res model can help, but with this model it only helps marginally. There's a lot of curved parts with strange anomalies on the sides, as well as the texture being straight up stretched on the base of the shaft... When I UV unwrap, I check for stretching, and it had very little if any.

If someone could help me out, that would be great. I've got notifications on for my posts so I should respond pretty promptly.

Here's a post with a bunch of photos of what I'm talking about, including the normal maps. https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0u60.jpg

And here's a link to download my Blender project. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oQ...Z1cr2sKJltFJeg

Thanks.
Here's some images of the normal map without, and with added edge loops to the low res model. I can remedy some of the stretching but it's still very messy. I also included an image of the high res model of the object.

[image][image]enter image description here

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please include any *relevant* pictures in the question body itself. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: The link to the file is not working. Could you zoom onto an area of the map that is interested by the issue and showing both the low and high poly portion of the mesh connected with that uv island?

Comment: I forgot a crucial step I learned early on, and it could have saved me so much time. There's an "Auto smoothing" option in the Data tab of blender.... it makes all the ugly shading and ugly normal stuff go away. I wish I had remembered that sooner.

Comment: Are you cage baking? I dont think Blender Guru teaches that.